# How many polygons are there whose vertices are the vertices of a regular 17-gon?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

I got 17 choose 3 times 17 choose 4 times 17 choose 5 times all they way to 17 choose 17. Am I correct?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "polygons in a 17-gon."  If you mean polygons whose vertices are vertices of a 17-gon, then it would be 17 choose 3 *plus* (not times) 17 choose 4 *plus* 17 choose 5, etc.

Comment: I changed the phrasing; hopefully its better.

Comment: Easier: There $2^{17}$ subsets of the vertices. Subtract the empty set, the one-element sets, and the two-element sets.

Comment: Yes, much better.  In which case does the plus, not times, part of my comment make sense?

Comment: @BarryCipra Ah, I see

Comment: @GerardL., good.  Hopefully Hagen's shortcut approach also makes sense.  You can post an answer to your question, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Start the count counting the different polygons we can build from a vertex. That is, if we choose a vertex in a regular $17$-gon then we can build from here

$$\sum_{k=2}^{16}\binom{16}{k}=2^{16}-17$$

different polygons, because for some set of vertex there is a unique possible polygon. Now change to the next vertex but this time you must count all possible polygons except these where the first vertex is involved, then this time we can build

$$\sum_{k=2}^{15}\binom{15}{k}=2^{15}-16$$

Then the total number of possible polygons is

$$\begin{align}\sum_{j=0}^{16}\sum_{k=2}^{j}\binom{j}{k}&=\sum_{j=2}^{16}(2^j-j-1)\\&=\sum\nolimits_2^{17}(2^j-j-1)\delta j\\&=\Big(2^j-\frac{j^{\underline 2}}2-j\Big)\Big|_2^{17}\\&=2^{17}-17\cdot8-17-(4-1-2)\\&=130918\end{align}$$

---

Equivalently, following the @Hagen comment we will have

$$\sum_{k=3}^{17}\binom{17}{k}=2^{17}-17\cdot 8-17-1=130918$$